# Control resizing of uploaded images

Tags: uploads, media, images

I am looking for the regular images that get uploaded from the media uploader. I want to put in an image resize script instead of using WordPress to manage the images. The main reason being is that I don't want 3 images created every time I upload an image. I want just the size that is chosen from the media uploader. I did some reading on this site and figured out how to get the sizes. Now I need to know if there is a hook that can grab the image? I have only ever worked with the thumbnail. Where are the regular images called from that get inserted into the body of the post?

Comment: I've seen, and personally answered, lots of Q&As dealing with this here in [wordpress.se]. Search for `wp_handle_upload_overrides`, `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced`, `wp_handle_upload_prefilter`, `wp_generate_attachment_metadata`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set your own image sizes from within your theme in `functions.php`?

```
add_image_size( 'some-image-size-name', 500, 300 );
```

Then you can call that size you want from your template.

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?>
```

Links

Add image size: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

get post thumbnail: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Comment: because that is the opposite of what I am trying to do. I am adding a custom script to my site to handle the images. I am going to use WordPress built in features with the script. If you add image size then it will add those sizes plus all the others. I am also not talking about the post thumbnail in this question

Comment: Oh, ok I see now.